# Nuclear operators - equivalent representations

Tags: functional-analysis

Hi in Dirk Werners book I am reading in the section on nuclear operators that these both representations are equivalent. But I don't really see how. Not sure what I am missing there.

$Tx = \sum_{n}^{\infty} x'_{n}(x)y_{n}$ with $\sum_{n}^{\infty} ||x'_{n}|| ||y_{n}||<\infty$ is equivalent to $Tx = \sum_{n}^{\infty} a_{n}x'_{n}(x)y_{n}$ with $||x'_{n}||=||y_{n}||=1$ and $(a_{n})\in \ell_{1}$.

Comment: Write the first sum as $\sum_n \lVert x_n'\rVert \lVert y_n\rVert\frac{x_n'}{\lVert x_n'\rVert }\frac{y_n}{\lVert y_n\rVert}$.

Comment: I thought about that but I still dont get it. I dont see how the $a_{n}$ enters the equation. I mean I could define $a_{n}$ as $||x_{n}'|| |||y_{n}||$ but then that would be just 1 which doesnt make sense.

Comment: You define $a_n$ exactly as you suggested, but it is not $1$, because the constraint on the norms of $x_n'$ and $y_n$ is not present in the first presentation. Note that you also have to redefine $x_n'$ and $y_n$.

Comment: Oh yeah now I see I just define $x_{n}'=\frac{x_{n}'}{||x_{n}||}$ and same for $y_{n}$ and they have norm 1 since they are normalizhed! Thanks! And $a_{n}$ is converging because of the contraint of the first presentation.